# Node.js: Why firing requests and forgot it can cause massive performance drop

Tags: node.js, networking

I found problem accidentally when I was sending Google Analytics events without waiting for response, so I built sample code here: https://github.com/tanapoln/node_perf_test

Code is very simple, just 2 endpoints, sending OK as response except for the slow one that will fire pageview event to GA (with HTTP request) as you can see below:

```
let express = require('express')
let ua = require('universal-analytics')

let app = express()
let visitor = ua('UA-34321454-1', 'user1', {strictCidFormat: false, https: false});

app.get('/fast', function(req ,res) {
    res.send('OK')
})

app.get('/slow', function(req, res) {
    //This line will simply fire HTTP request to Google Analytics
    visitor.pageview('/slow').send()
    res.send('OK')
})

app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log("Server started at port 3000")
})
```

When benchmarking these 2 endpoints, you can see resule here:

```
Running 10s test @ http://localhost:3000/fast
  10 threads and 500 connections
  Thread Stats   Avg      Stdev     Max   +/- Stdev
    Latency   103.83ms   59.20ms 698.91ms   85.15%
    Req/Sec   201.36    113.56   750.00     79.63%
  19531 requests in 10.06s, 3.73MB read
  Socket errors: connect 0, read 659, write 0, timeout 0
Requests/sec:   1941.10
Transfer/sec:    379.12KB


Running 10s test @ http://localhost:3000/slow
  10 threads and 500 connections
  Thread Stats   Avg      Stdev     Max   +/- Stdev
    Latency   407.06ms  228.33ms   1.23s    74.15%
    Req/Sec    37.18     29.17   136.00     70.59%
  2847 requests in 10.09s, 556.05KB read
  Socket errors: connect 0, read 2900, write 1, timeout 0
Requests/sec:    282.10
Transfer/sec:     55.10KB
```

Request per second drop massively and I don't know the reasons why.

Please help.

Comment: I don't know why it would slow your overall process down, but I suspect that GA will be rate limiting you when it sees so many requests coming from one IP address since that is obviously not a real world use of their API.  You could find out if the issue was GA specific by replace the GA call with a call to another simple server of your own that just returns an immediate response.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thank you for your response, I already try changing endpoint with simple GET request but result is the same as before (but req/sec is higher around 20%). I also try benchmarking that mock endpoint to ensure it don't be a bottleneck.

Comment: Does node.js have something do with NIO?

Answer (score 1):

I think problem is not live inside Node.js which I also tried with another language (in my case, Go) which I found same problem with same performance limitation.

This is far beyond my current knowledges. I guess that problem is live inside linux/unix TCP stack or even at lower level.

I will close this and do more research. If I hit a road block, I'll post another question again.

Thanks everyone.